# How to change the href attirbute of a <link> tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to change the href attribute of link tag on a button click. However i am not able to achieve it. It throws me an error **The stylesheet https://www.w3resource.com/ was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.** Please help, My code is a below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button1').click(function() {
    $("#styleit").attr('href', 'https://www.w3resource.com/');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="a.css" rel="stylesheet" id="styleit">

<p><input id="button1" type="button" value="Click to see the actual url" /></p>
```

Comment: If you use an actual stylesheet URL, like `https://www.w3resource.com/assets/mdl/additional.css`, it'll probably start working.

Comment: Thanks a ton! this works but one more thing i am trying is how to apply the style rules of the changed css link to the current page after this?

Comment: They are applied automatically